# Phonegap WebSQL DELETE row not work on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, cordova, web-sql

I have two functions:

```
function removePreorder(id) {


        db.transaction(function(tx) {

           tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM preorder WHERE id= ?", [id], removeRow(id));
            console.log ('ok');

        });
      }
function removeRow(id) {
         $( "#"+id+"" ).remove();

     }
```

Function `removePreorder()` binded on click event on `href`.

function renderResults(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;

```
    var preorder = [];
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        preorder.push( "<tr id ='"+results.rows.item(i).id+"'><td>"+results.rows.item(i).name+"</td><td>"+results.rows.item(i).tel+"</td><td>"+results.rows.item(i).email+"</td><td>"+results.rows.item(i).size+"</td><td><a href='#'onclick='removePreorder("+results.rows.item(i).id+")' class='button [tiny small success alert]'>remove</a></td></tr>" );

    }
```

On Mac in chrome all this functions work correctly.

`removePreorder()` delete row from WebSQL table and `removeRow()` remove DOM object from page.

On iPad function `removePreorder()` does not delete row from WebSQL table, but `removeRow()` removes DOM object from page.

What is the problem?

Comment: where are the success and error handlers?

Comment: success handler is removeRow(), error handler not needed. Base problem all things work in chrome on Mac or PC, but after build this app with phonegap this function - removePreorder() doesn't  work

Comment: I doubt you can pass `id` in success handler `removeRow(id)`

Comment: I can, this part work and it remove DOM object from page. Maybe problem in premissons for DELETE command in webSQL?

Answer (score 0):

problem in

```
 tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS preorder (id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT, name TEXT, tel TEXT, email TEXT, art TEXT, size TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (id))');
```

this right

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "preorder" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "name" TEXT , "tel" TEXT, "email" TEXT, "art" TEXT, "size" TEXT);');
```

AUTOINCREMENT field on ipad return undefined